# Pass parent id while inserting in 2 columns with one-to-one relation

Tags: laravel, eloquent, laravel-8

I have 2 columns with one-to-one relation `users` and `doctors`:

```
    Users
_____________
| id | name |
|____|______|
| 1  | John |
|____|______|


        Doctors
_____________________
| id | dep | user_id |
|____|_____|_________|
| 1  |  2  |    1    |
|____|_____|_________|
```

`User` model has this function that returns the doctor with relation:

```
public function doctor(){
    return $this->hasOne(Doctor::class);
}
```

Inserting data:

```
$valdiated = $request->validated();

$userData = [
    'name' => $valdiated['name'],
];

$doctorData = [
    'dep' => $valdiated['dep'],
];

$newUser = new User();
$newUser->insert($userData);
$newUser->doctor()->insert($doctorData);
```

But I'm getting this error:

```
SQLSTATE[23000]: Integrity constraint violation: 1452 Cannot add or update a child row: a foreign key constraint fails (`db`.`doctors`, CONSTRAINT `doctors_user_id_foreign` FOREIGN KEY (`user_id`) REFERENCES `users` (`id`) ON DELETE CASCADE ON UPDATE CASCADE) (SQL: insert into `doctors` (`dep`) values (2))
```

Is there a way to insert the `user_id` into `doctors` table or I have to query the database and get the last id?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should use `create()` instead of `insert` since it will return a instance of the new `Model` that you just created. Then you will use the `doctor()` to create a associated to the doctor table.

```
$newUser = User::create($userData);
$newDoctor = $newUser->doctor()->create($doctorData);

dd($newUser,$newDoctor); //Just to check if the data is inserted.
```

Answer (score 0):

I think the issue is using `->insert()`; that doesn't perform any kind of linking logic on the associated Model, so `user_id` would be `null`, as it is not present in `$doctorData`.

You can use `->create()` instead:

```
$newUser = User::create($userData);
$newUser->doctor()->create($doctorData);
```